# Raid Won't Mount After Reboot

Tags: raid, mdadm

I'm building a new Ubuntu 14.04 server with RAID. I partitioned the operating system and swap partition on a small harddrive and have the RAID strictly for files. After adding a new disc to the RAID, it now won't let me mount it.

```
guy@server:~$ sudo mountall
swapon: /dev/disk/by-uuid/ab5617d1-58e1-4013-9690-64679982b2cf: swapon failed: Device or resource busy
mountall: swapon /dev/disk/by-uuid/ab5617d1-58e1-4013-9690-64679982b2cf [1823] terminated with status 255
mountall: Problem activating swap: /dev/disk/by-uuid/ab5617d1-58e1-4013-9690-64679982b2cf
```

Here's my fstab:

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=d24a5068-14fb-4cec-831a-4b6d3bdba44d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro     0       1
/dev/mapper/VG--RAID-LV--RAID /pangolin       ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ab5617d1-58e1-4013-9690-64679982b2cf none            swap    sw                  0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

And the output of mdadm --examine /dev/sda1

```
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : c091b97c:00578039:f0b8ae04:c6b0c1a8
           Name : Pangolin:0  (local to host Pangolin)
  Creation Time : Tue Jan 25 16:11:29 2005
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 1953259520 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Array Size : 2929887744 (2794.16 GiB 3000.21 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953258496 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4aa877c8:b7187071:2237883c:c0bf754d

    Update Time : Thu Jul 24 16:59:25 2014
       Checksum : 24f84274 - correct
         Events : 276

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

Any help understanding what's going on would be appreciated.

EDIT: Okay, I feel dumb. I just had to stop the array, and then reassemble it, and then do mountall.